# git status print Untracked files first

Tags: git

Is it possible to configure git to print Untracked files first when doing `git status`?
Currently, the printout when doing `git status` is something like stated below.
Note: I do not want to use the ignore functionality. All files that are untracked shall be printed.

```
# Changes to be committed:
#  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   somefile.c
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   anotherfile.c
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#    Alot of files.
#   .
#   .
#   .
```

Comment: Does the print order matter ?

Comment: AFAIK, git doesn't have this option. If the order matter so much, @cupcake's answer is probably the way to go.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, you also have the option to upvote it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `sort` command available that sorts in reverse, you could try this:

```
git status --short | sort -r
```

which gives this output in msysgit 1.9.0:

```
?? foo.txt
 M hello.scala
```

In the output above, untracked files are shown with `??` before them. [As the documentation states](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html#_short_format):

> For untracked paths, XY are ??.

Also note that the short form of the `--short` flag is `-s`, so this can also be used:

```
git status -s | sort -r
```

#### Aliases

If you want, you could even turn this into a git alias:

```
git config --global rstatus "!git status --short | sort -r"

# Usage
git rstatus
```

Or you could define an alias in your Bash config:

```
alias gsr='git status --short | sort -r'

# Usage
grs
```